# Object getting pushed multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

The problem I am facing is that I only want to push "historyEntry"  once every time I checkout button instead whenever I click on check out it is creating a "historyEntry" object for each cart item present in the cart
basically, I just want a single historyEntry push into local storage for every checkout!

```
function updateCartItems() {
  // Get the cart items element
  const cartItemsElement = document.getElementById('middlecart');

  // Get the cart data from local storage
  const cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));


  
  cart.forEach(item => {
    let qty = item.qty;
    //updating price according to qty
    let price = item.price*qty;
    const li = document.createElement('div');

    
    
    function Totalprice() {
      let totalPrice = 0;
      cart.forEach(item => {
        let qty = item.qty;
        let price = item.price * qty;
        totalPrice += price;
      });
      const totalPriceElement = document.getElementById('total-price');
      const Shipprice = document.getElementById('ship-price');
      const Finalprice = document.getElementById('final-price');
      var ship;
      totalPriceElement.innerHTML = `$${totalPrice.toFixed(2)}`;
      if (totalPrice <= 50 ) {
        Shipprice.innerHTML = `$25`;
        ship = 25 
      } else {
        Shipprice.innerHTML = `FREE`;
        ship = 0
      }
      Finalprice.innerHTML = `$${totalPrice.toFixed(2) + ship}`;
      
      
      
    }
    

    Totalprice()
    
    

    cartItemsElement.appendChild(li);
    
    
    
  });
```

> This is the important part but whole code was necessary

```
    const checkout = document.getElementById('checkout')
      checkout.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const p = document.getElementById('final-price').innerText
        const historyEntry = { Finalprice: p};
        history.push(historyEntry)
        localStorage.setItem('history', JSON.stringify(history));
        
        localStorage.removeItem("cart");
      })
}
const history = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('history'));
history.forEach(orders => {
  console.log(orders.Finalprice)
  
});


// Call the updateCartItems function when the page is loaded
updateCartItems();
```

Comment: Figure out how to use a debugger, put a breakpoint on the push statement, and see why it is being called more than you expect

Comment: if this is your entire code, you have an extra **}**

Comment: @medelito I removed some of  the code to stay relevant to the problem

Comment: can you put the entire code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: The first part of code is useless to us because it never modifies the `history` variable, if there is other code that uses this variable, you should add it. My intuition is either this variable is used elsewhere, either there are programmatic "clicks" on the button